# Reverse the cycle of sliding div's in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML part:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>
```

Javascript part:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});​
```

CSS part:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
​
```

When the above code is complied and div's in the pages are clicked they move towards their left. I want the div's to slide towards right in the opposite direction. I know this might be very easy for people who know jQuery but I hardly have any knowledge of this script but I like the way it functions. Link to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/  All the help is appreciated.

Comment: And I also don't understand how the boxes 1-5 are getting positioned since nothing has been mentioned in their css or script or html about their position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '150%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '-150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().css({
        left: '-150%'
    }, 500);
    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/4148/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never got an answer so fast.

Comment: In your answer the divs are getting animated from left to right but sequence should not get messed up. I mean after div 5 div 4 should come. The order should be the same as that of the example i mentioned in my link. but in reverse direction. The desired sequence 5-4-3-2-1-5

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">

<div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
<div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
<div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>


$('.box').click(function() {

$(this).animate({
    right: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('right', '150%');
    $(this).appendTo('#container');
});

$(this).next().animate({
    right: '50%'
}, 500);
});​


body {
padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 300px;
line-height: 300px;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid black;
right: 150%;
top: 100px;
margin-right: -25%;
}

#box1 {
background-color: green;
right: 50%;
}

#box2 {
background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
background-color: blue;
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never got an answer so fast.